# Identify bad requests(4xx response code) from navigator.sendBeacon()

Tags: navigator, sendbeacon

How can I get response code from **navigator.sendBeacon**? I need to have some indicator that can say me that request is failed? Particularly,  I am looking for a way to identify bad request (request that was send with “bad” malformed json and got 4xx response code). Is there any way to do it while using sendBeacon?

From documentation:

> The sendBeacon() method returns true if the user agent is able to
>   successfully queue the data for transfer, Otherwise it returns false.

So, it is not returning false if request is invalid.(and response code is 4xx)

navigator.sendBeacon(that.sushiEndpoint, sushiPayload)

Comment: I have the same question.  Maybe commenting on this will bring it back to the front pages after so long without an answer.